# Kivy Buildozer Zipfile Error: 98 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile

Tags: android, python, macos, kivy, buildozer

Upgraded to new buildozer version (Running Kivy,Python and Buildozer on OS X).

Please assist if anyone has picked up similar errors with the android_new branch.

When trying to package a new distribution I'm getting the following zip file errors when running the buildozer command:

```
buildozer android_new debug
```

Log Output
(note: deleted some output due to body limitations on the post size)

```
# Run 'python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-   dir=/Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build create --dist_name=rides10 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,python2 --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs'
# Cwd /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[INFO]:    Using Google NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.6', '4.8', 'clang3.3']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.8
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[INFO]:    Bootstrap requires recipes ['sdl2', ('python2', 'python3crystax')]
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe sdl2 (depends on [('python2', 'python3crystax'), 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf'], conflicts ['sdl', 'pygame', 'pygame_bootstrap_components'])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe kivy (depends on ['pyjnius', ('sdl2', 'pygame'), ('python2', 'python3crystax')])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe python2 (depends on ['hostpython2'], conflicts ['python3crystax', 'python3'])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe sdl2_image (depends on [])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe sdl2_mixer (depends on [])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe sdl2_ttf (depends on [])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe pyjnius (depends on ['six', ('sdl2', 'sdl', 'genericndkbuild'), ('python2', 'python3crystax')])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe hostpython2 (depends on [], conflicts ['hostpython3'])
[INFO]:    Loaded recipe six (depends on [('python2', 'python3crystax')])
[INFO]:    Found a single valid recipe set (this is good)
[INFO]:    The selected bootstrap is sdl2
[INFO]:    # Creating dist with sdl2 bootstrap
[INFO]:    Dist will have name rides10 and recipes (kivy, python2)
[INFO]:    -> running cp -r /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/plat...(and 200 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Recipe build order is ['hostpython2', 'sdl2_image', 'sdl2_mixer', 'sdl2_ttf', 'python2', 'sdl2', 'six', 'pyjnius', u'kivy']
[INFO]:    # Downloading recipes 
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 34 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/hostpython2
[INFO]:    -> running basename http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython2 from http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Downloading hostpython2 from http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 33 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_image
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_image from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
Downloading sdl2_image from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 33 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_mixer
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_mixer from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
Downloading sdl2_mixer from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 31 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2_ttf
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2_ttf from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
Downloading sdl2_ttf from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading python2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 30 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/python2
[INFO]:    -> running basename http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    Downloading python2 from http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Downloading python2 from http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 27 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/sdl2
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading sdl2 from https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
Downloading sdl2 from https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading six
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 26 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/six
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-six-1.9.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading six from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz
Downloading six from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-six-1.9.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 30 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/pyjnius
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-master.zip
[INFO]:    Downloading pyjnius from https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip
Downloading pyjnius from https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-master.zip
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/p...(and 27 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
[WARNING]: Should check headers here! Skipping for now.                                                                                    
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-master.zip
[INFO]:    Downloading kivy from https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
Downloading kivy from https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
[INFO]:    -> running touch .mark-master.zip
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    # Building all recipes for arch armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    # Unpacking recipes
[INFO]:    Unpacking hostpython2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython2/desktop
[INFO]:    -> running tar tf /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/pla...(and 53 more)
[INFO]:    -> running mv Python-2.7.2 /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/an...(and 71 more)           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/jni
[INFO]:    -> running tar tf /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/pla...(and 55 more)
[INFO]:    -> running mv SDL2_image-2.0.1 /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildoze...(and 75 more)           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-2.0.1.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/jni
[INFO]:    -> running tar tf /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/pla...(and 55 more)
[INFO]:    -> running mv SDL2_mixer-2.0.1 /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildoze...(and 75 more)           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.14.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/jni
[INFO]:    -> running tar tf /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/pla...(and 52 more)
[INFO]:    -> running mv SDL2_ttf-2.0.14 /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer...(and 72 more)           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking python2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tar.bz2
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/python2/armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running tar tf /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/pla...(and 49 more)
[INFO]:    -> running mv Python-2.7.2 /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/an...(and 67 more)           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.4.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python2/jni
[INFO]:    -> running tar tf /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/pla...(and 43 more)
[INFO]:    -> running mv SDL2-2.0.4 /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/andr...(and 62 more)           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking six for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.9.0.tar.gz
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/six-python2/armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running tar tf /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/pla...(and 41 more)
[INFO]:    -> running mv six-1.9.0 /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/andro...(and 64 more)           
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/archive/master.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running mv pyjnius-master /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/...(and 82 more)
[INFO]:    <- directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Unpacking kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
[INFO]:    -> directory context /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/kivy-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 755, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 752, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 341, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)(unknown)
  File "/Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 93, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, dist_args)
  File "/Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 138, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 547, in build_recipes
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 542, in prepare_build_dir
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 427, in unpack
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1021, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 486, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 500, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 516, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc(self.ran, self.process.stdout, self.process.stderr)
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: '/usr/bin/unzip /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy/master.zip'

  STDOUT:
Archive:  /Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy/master.zip
6f36c128140ced158b8c3df356fc4bd549320a63
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf  
   creating: kivy-master/kivy/data/glsl/
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/glsl/default.fs  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/glsl/default.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/glsl/default.vs  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/glsl/header.fs  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/glsl/header.vs  
   creating: kivy-master/kivy/data/images/
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/images/background.jpg  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme-0.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme.atlas  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/images/image-loading.gif  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/data/images/testpattern.png  
   creating: kivy-master/kivy/data/keyboards/
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/image-missing.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/media-playback-pause.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/media-playback-start.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/media-playback-stop.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/modalview-background.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/overflow.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/player-background.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/player-play-overlay.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/previous_normal.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/progressbar.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/progressbar_background.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/ring.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/selector_left.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/selector_middle.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/selector_right.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/tree_closed.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/tree_opened.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/vkeyboard_background.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/vkeyboard_disabled_background.png  
 extracting: kivy-master/kivy/tools/theming/defaulttheme/vkeyboard_disabled_key_down.png  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/uix/tabbedpanel.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/uix/textinput.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/uix/togglebutton.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/uix/treeview.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/uix/video.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/uix/videoplayer.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/uix/vkeyboard.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/uix/widget.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/utils.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/vector.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/weakmethod.py  
  inflating: kivy-master/kivy/weakproxy.pyx  
  inflating: kivy-master/setup.cfg   
  inflating: kivy-master/setup.py    


  STDERR:
warning [/Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build/packages/kivy/master.zip]:  98 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  98
  (attempting to re-compensate)
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  98
file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  51
  (attempting to re-compensate)
file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  51
file #3:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  410
file #4:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  982
file #5:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  3065
file #6:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  3923
file #7:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  5265
file #8:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  5959
file #9:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  6177
file #10:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  7846
file #11:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9785
file #12:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9840
file #13:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  11610
file #14:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  12107
file #15:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  12173
file #16:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  14649
file #17:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  14828
file #18:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18786
file #19:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18849
file #20:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18920
file #21:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  19240
file #22:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  19540
file #23:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  20461
file #24:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  21030
file #25:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  21761
file #26:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  22457
file #816:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18760584
file #817:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18761720
file #818:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18763801
file #819:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18763869
file #820:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18777297
file #821:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18780997
file #822:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18782222
file #823:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18786765
file #824:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18792899
file #825:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18795273
file #826:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18799739
file #827:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18814609
file #828:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18814670
file #829:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  18814737

# Command failed: python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain --color=always --storage-dir=/Users/kiiron/Desktop/kiiron/rides-18-06-2016-ObjectsWorking/.buildozer/android/platform/build create --dist_name=rides10 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,python2 --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this has started happening, but it apparently can affect all the github .zip files. I pushed a workaround to the p4a master branch earlier today though (it just ignores the error as the extraction still works), so it should hopefully work if you upgrade to master. You can make buildozer re-download the master version by deleting the `.buildozer` folder in your app directory.

Comment: Thanks @inclement. Will try it and hopefully it will work